# Rails drag-and-drop сортировка Sortable Tables - не сохраняется позиция строки

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Подключил `gem 'ranked-model'` для `drag-and-drop` сортировки таблицы. Пример реализации брал отсюда [http://benw.me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWXYJ.png).

Строки таблицы перемещаются - но при перезагрузке страницы, измененное расположения строк не сохраняется. Подскажите как побороть данную проблему?

## Контроллер:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tasks = Task.rank(:row_order).all
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def update_row_order
    @task = Task.find(task_params[:task_id])
    @task.row_order_position = task_params[:row_order_position]
    @task.save

    render nothing: true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view rendered
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@task) }
        format.html { redirect_to(@task, :notice => 'Task was successfully updated.') }
      else
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@task) }
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end

  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_path, success: 'Product destroyed successfully' }
      format.js {}
    end

  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:task_id, :name, :row_order_position)
  end

end
```

## Скрипт:

```
assets/javascript/update_things_row_order.js.coffee:

jQuery ->
  if $('#sortable').length > 0
    table_width = $('#sortable').width()
    cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length
    desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px'
    $('.table td').css('width', desired_width)

    $('#sortable').sortable(
      axis: 'y'
      items: '.item'
      cursor: 'move'

      sort: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow')
      stop: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow')
        # highlight the row on drop to indicate an update
        ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
      update: (e, ui) ->
        item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
        console.log(item_id)
        position = ui.item.index() # this will not work with paginated items, as the index is zero on every page
        $.ajax(
          type: 'POST'
          url: '/tasks/update_row_order'
          dataType: 'json'
          data: { task: {task_id: item_id, row_order_position: position } }
        )
    )
```

## View:

```
tasks/index.html.erb:

<div class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <h1>TASK#PAGE</h1>

  <%= form_for(@task, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control ' %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= f.submit 'Добавить', class: 'btn btn-success btn-secondary' %>
      </span>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <br>
  <table id="sortable" class="tasks table table-striped">

    <%= render @tasks %>

  </table>
</div>
```

## partial:

```
tasks/_task.html.erb

<tr id="row_<%= task.id %>" data-item-id=<%= "#{task.id}" %> class="item">
  <td><%= check_box_tag(:task) %></td>
  <td id="task-name" style="width: 90%"><%= best_in_place task, :name %></td>

  <td><%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>'.html_safe, task_path(task), remote: true,
                  class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs',
                  method: :delete,
                  data: {confirm: 'Вы уверены?'} %></td>
</tr>
```

Ошибки при отработке AJAX в браузере не вижу

[image: AJAX запрос (консоль браузера)]

## Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/index'

  get 'devise' => 'sessions#new'

  devise_for :users

  resources :profiles
  resources :projects
  resources :tasks do
    post :update_row_order, on: :collection
  end

  root 'home#index'
```

## Модель:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RankedModel
  ranks :row_order

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Comment: Выкладывай контроллер, форму, javascript, лог из консоли Rails, и самое главное - роуты.

Comment: Добавил view, Routes.rb, javascript, модель, контроллер + скриншот консоли браузера

Comment: Судя по всему проблема в там что я при помощи AJAX  добавляю и удаляю данные в таблице. Если сделать таблицу как в примере - без AJAX отрабатывает нормально. Теперь не понимаю что не так с рендерингом было и как нужно правильно его настроить

Comment: Скриншот консоли Rails нужен, либо логи.

Comment: `post :update_row_order, on: :collection` замените на `post :update_row_order, on: :member`. Вы ведь обращаетесь к члену коллекции, а не к коллекции